# how to add azure devops repo as flux source

Tags: azure-devops, flux

I'm trying to add azure devops repo as source for flux using SSH authentication. Im using below command :

```
flux create source git test-gitrepo --url="ssh://<user>@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com/<org>/<orgname with space>/reponame" --branch=master --private-key-file=./private-key
```

But im getting "ssh: handshake failed: EOF" error.

As orgname has space in its name, I tried keeping url in double quotes, I kept %20 instead of space. But in all of the cases same error is coming.

Can somebody tell me how to add repo in flux.

I bootstrapped flux with devops PAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Flux on an AKS cluster using an Azure DevOps Git repository as the source of truth, you can use the [flux bootstrap git](https://fluxcd.io/flux/installation/bootstrap/generic-git-server/) command.

To bootstrap using a SSH key instead of a Azure DevOps PAT, run:

```
flux bootstrap git \
  --url=ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/<org>/<project>/<repository>
  --branch=<my-branch> \
  --private-key-file=<path/to/ssh/private.key> \
  --password=<key-passphrase> \
  --path=clusters/my-cluster
```

See [Flux bootstrap for Azure DevOps](https://fluxcd.io/flux/installation/bootstrap/azure-devops/) for details.

**UPDATE:**

As santosh.a clarified, it turned out that `port 22` was blocked by the firewall. The issue was resolved after opening port 22 in the firewall.

Comment: I used same approach but I get below error in the logs:

{"level":"error","ts":"2023-10-09T10:40:07.137Z","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"gitrepository","controllerGroup":"source.toolkit.fluxcd.io","controllerKind":"GitRepository","GitRepository":{"name":"flux-system","namespace":"flux-system"},"namespace":"flux-system","name":"flux-system","reconcileID":"c0d7437c-b967-40d9-add1-3231c909aebc","error":"failed to checkout and determine revision: unable to clone 'ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/orgname/projectname_with_space/test-fleet': ssh: handshake failed: EOF"}.

Comment: is this because it has space in project name?

Comment: @santosh.a It doesn't seem to be related to the space. Can you git clone the repo from your local machine with the same private key?  `git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/<org>/<project>/<repository>` . See [Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) for details.

Comment: hey, issue is resolved.  since FW is blocking 22 port i was getting EOF error. once I opened FW issue is resolved

Comment: @santosh.a Well, missed the simplest cause. Anyway, glad to know that the issue has been resolved. I have updated that in above answer. Alternately, you can post your own and Accept it as an Answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. Thanks